# DS18B20 & Pi 3+

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, ds18b20

I'm not getting a w1_slave, and all I'm getting is 00-xx0000 when the DS18B20 isn't burning my fingertip. I went for green for ground, which is on the top right plug from this perspective. I spliced some mobo power cables to come Cat6 for the sake of a throwaway breadbording. The white and red plugged into the pi board is spliced to the orange & O/W that's on the breadboard.

[image: my temp wiring setup]

This is my first attempt at doing any wiring anything with a Pi that isn't just "ping & wol" or something similar. Any tips welcome.

Comment: Did you enable 1-wire in raspi-config (or the GUI equivalent)?

Comment: Yes and it still got stupid hot.

Comment: To make the wiring easier to follow, I am going to do a little more reworking and stuff

Comment: If it gets "stupid hot" you have reversed the power and ground connections.

Comment: And probably the DS18B20  is broken.